# What this condition means if (null == (is = con.getErrorStream()))

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was searching on the internet for how to do an http request when I founnd this:

```
InputStream is;
if (null == (is = con.getErrorStream())) {
        is = con.getInputStream();
    }
```

What this condition does exactly? When this condition is checked will `is` variable take the value that `con.getErrorStream()` returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `is` will take the value that `con.getErrorStream()` returns and then `is` is compared to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is;
if (con.getErrorStream() == null) {
    is = con.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: Not quite. In this code, is might never get assigned. In OP's code, is is either the error stream (if it is not null) or the input stream.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, since it doesn't assign the result of `con.getErrorStream()` to `is` before the condition is checked. The real equivalent would be `InputStream is = con.getErrorStream(); if (is == null) { is = con.getInputStream(); }`

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Really Stephan? If `con.getErrorStream == null` will the code that daniel answered initialize `is` to `con.getErrorStream()`?